# Better way to create my lists in classes?

Tags: python, list, variables, global

I've been working on making my text based game more realistic, and one design I would like to implement is to make sure the rooms stay 'static' to a point (i.e. a player uses a potion in the room, if they come back to that room that potion should no longer be there.)

This is how my code is basically set up (I have been using "Learn Python The Hard Way" by Zed Shaw so my code is set up much in the same way):

```
class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."

class Room(Scene):
    potions = []
    for i in range(3):
        potions.append(Potion())

    def enter(self):
        ...
```

When I run this, I get a `NameError: global name 'potions' is not defined`. I know I can fix this one of two ways: 1. make potions a global variable, but then I would have to make a new list for each room that contains potions (There are 36 rooms in total, set up as a 6x6 grid) OR 
2. Put this line of code in the enter function, but that would cause the list to reset to 3 potions each time the user enters the room.

```
potions = []
for i in range(3):
    potions.append(Potion())
```

If there's no other way, I suppose declaring a new variable for all the rooms that contain potions (There's only 5). But my question is if there's another way of making this work without making it a global.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

First, let's look at your example (I'll simplify it):

```
class Room(Scene):
   potions = [Potion() for x in range(3)]
```

What you have done there is create a class attribute `potions` that are shared among *all* instances of `Room`.  For example, you'll see my potions in each of my rooms are the same instances of potions (the hex number is the same!).  If I modify the `potions` list in one instance, it modifies the same list in all of the `Room` instances:

```
>>> room1.potions
[<__main__.Potion instance at 0x7f63552cfb00>, <__main__.Potion instance at 0x7f63552cfb48>, <__main__.Potion instance at 0x7f63552cfb90>]
>>> room2.potions
[<__main__.Potion instance at 0x7f63552cfb00>, <__main__.Potion instance at 0x7f63552cfb48>, <__main__.Potion instance at 0x7f63552cfb90>]
>>>
```

It sounds like you want `potions` to be a unique attribute of each *instance* of a `Room`.

Somewhere you will be instantiating a room, e.g., `room = Room()`.  You need to write your constructor for your `Room` in order to customize your instance:

```
class Room(Scene):
    def __init__(self): # your constructor, self refers to the Room instance.
        self.potions = [Potion() for x in range(3)]
```

Now when you create your room instance, it will contain 3 potions.

You now need to think about how you will make your rooms instances persist between entrances by your characters.  That will need to be some sort of variable that persists throughout the game.

This idea of object composition will extend through your game.  Perhaps you have a `Dungeon` class that has your 36 rooms:

```
class Dungeon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rooms = [[Room() for x in range(6)] for x in range(6)]
```

Or perhaps your rooms have up to four doors, and you link them up into something potentially less square:

```
class Room(Scene):
    def __init__(self, north_room, east_room, south_room, west_room):
        self.north_door = north_room
        self.east_door = east_room
        [... and so on ...]
        # Note: You could pass `None` for doors that don't exist.
```

Or even more creatively,

```
class Room(Scene):
    def __init__(self, connecting_rooms): # connecting_rooms is a dict
        self.connecting_rooms = connecting_rooms
```

Except both examples will get you a chicken and egg problem for connecting rooms, so it is better to add a method to add each room connection:

```
class Room(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rooms = {}
        # ... initialize your potions ...
    def connect_room(self, description, room):
        self.rooms[description] = room
```

Then you could do:

```
room = Room()
room.connect_room("rusty metal door", room1)
room.connect_room("wooden red door", room2)
room.connect_room("large hole in the wall", room3)
```

Then perhaps your dungeon looks like this:

```
class Dungeon(Scene):
    def __init__(self, initial_room):
        self.entrance = initial_room
```

Now in the end, you just have to hold onto your `dungeon` instance of `Dungeon` for the duration of the game.

btw, this construct of "rooms" connected by "paths" is called a [Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)).